# Don't reload the page when click Delete

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

I have a little page, shopping cart type, and i do want to make some changes in the code. When I click delete,  the item will be deleteld, without reloading the page. I tryed, but it doesn't work. Anybody?
So I updated the post and i put All the HTML code, here is everything.

```
<?php  

require_once "conectare.php";

if($_SESSION['admin_logat'] == false) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY id ASC";
$products = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


    
function trimite(e){
    let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange=function(r){
                if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 ){
                    document.getElementById("RezervatAfisare").innerHTML=r
                }
                xhr.open('POST','product_delete.php',true);
            xhr.send('id='+e.target.dataset.id);
}
function procesareRaspuns()
    {
    if ((cerere.readyState==4)&&(cerere.status==200))
        {
        raspuns=cerere.responseText
        document.getElementById("RezervatAfisare").innerHTML=raspuns
        }
    }
    
</script> 
    <title>PRODUCTS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="gestionare_produse.php">PRODUCTS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="gestionare_clienti.php">CLIENTS</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">LOGOUT</button></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

    <h1>MANAGE PRODUCTS</h1>
    <br><br>
    <a href="product_new.php"><button class="btn btn-primary">NEW PRODUCT</button></a><br><br>

    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            <?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $product['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo strtok($product['description'], " ") . "..."; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['code']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "<img src=../images/".$product['image']." style='width:50px' alt=".$product['image'].">"; ?></td>
                    <td><a class="action" href="<?php echo "product_edit.php?id=" .$product['id'];  ?>">Edit</a></td>
                 <td> <a class="action" data-id='<?php echo $product['id'];?>' onclick="trimite(this.value)">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

<?php 
    mysqli_close($con);
 ?> 
and here is the product_delete.php
<?php

    session_start();
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    require_once "conectare.php";
    
    
    if( empty( $_SESSION['admin_logat'] ) ) {
        exit( header("Location: login.php") );
    }
    
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['id'] ) ){
    
        
        
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        
        $sql='delete from `tbl_product` where `id`=? order by `id` limit 1';
        $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param( 'i', $id );
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows=$stmt->affected_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        
        
        exit( $rows ? 'OK' : 'FAILED' );
    }
    
?>
```

this is the script i tryed to do, but it doesn't work

So I updated the post and i put All the HTML code

Comment: when you say `"it doesn't work"` could you clarify what doesn't work? Does the item / record not get deleted or does the page reload?

Comment: I would also suggest using `POST` rather than `GET` for this type of sql command and also using `Prepared Statements` as you code is wide open to sql injection attacks

Comment: So, in the first place it worked, but was reloading the page. So I  tryed to use the javascript, because i dont want to reload the page

Comment: Well the javascript function is using `this.value` as it's argument. A button or other INPUT element will have a value but a hyperlink does not so you are not passing an ID to the backend php script. It is unclear where there is a HTML element with that ID value as you have only shown a little html. Perhaps add the full html form?

Comment: I just updated. Thank you for your interest Professor Abronsius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hyperlink does NOT have a value attribute but you can change the it to have a ( or many ) dataset` attribute(s). If you add a dataset attribute you can easily access that from within your javascript function.

```
<a class="action" data-id='<?php echo $product['id'];?>' onclick="trimite(event)">Delete</a>
```

I mentioned it is better to use `POST` than `GET` for this type of operation - the reason: you can bookmark such a request and easily tamper with the querystring parameters whereas with POST it is not so trivial. Also, loosely, GET is usually for retrieving data and POST is for performing updates of some sort.

```
<script>
    function trimite(e){
    
        e.preventDefault();
        
        let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange=function(r){
                if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 ){
                    document.getElementById("RezervatAfisare").innerHTML=r
                }
            }
            xhr.open('POST','product_delete.php',true);
            xhr.send('id='+e.target.dataset.id);
    }
</script>
```

The PHP code is vulnerable to SQL injection - to mitigate that threat you should adopt `Prepared Statements` with bound parameters.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    require_once "conectare.php";
    
    
    if( empty( $_SESSION['admin_logat'] ) ) {
        exit( header("Location: login.php") );
    }
    
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['id'] ) ){
    
        
        
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        
        $sql='delete from `tbl_product` where `id`=? order by `id` limit 1';
        $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param( 'i', $id );
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows=$stmt->affected_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        
        
        exit( $rows ? 'OK' : 'FAILED' );
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: So, if I replace the php part as you said, I'm having an error here <?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)) { ?> because you used a diffrent approach, which i dont understand. so, instead of products now i should use stmt?

Comment: is the html/php page you showed above `product_delete` or a different one? I moved the database connection out of the `if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['id'] ) ){` block

Comment: I updated the the code, take a look. It still doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you see happening in the developer console?  Are you able to observe the Http request? If yes, are there errors? Are there any errors listed in the console at all on page load? When you say `"it doesn't work"` - please clarify what does not work

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasan't specific. So, when I'm clicking on "Delete"  on the webpage, nothing happening. the product is still there

Comment: re: previous comment. Do you observe Http request (ajax/XHR) request?